# How do I import a Java project into my workspace correctly and make it run?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

i am new to microservices, to Docker and Spring and followed the instructions [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) how to install Spring, that is, how to make a Spring project. Then there is the hint to Spring initializr https://start.spring.io/ which produces a zip file which is obviously a Java project. I am new to Java and eclipse. I have Maven installed. The first tripping stone was, that I didn't know what to enter in the field "Group" so I entered something like `docker-spring-test`. I then downloaded the `.zip` file.

In Eclipse I went to `File -> Import -> General -> Archive File` which lead the contents of the generated zip file to be extracted into my workspace and there into the namespace folder `/com.something/`.

Was that correct? What do I do with that now? In the directory tree in Eclipse it can now be found under the `com.something` project tree. When I select the file containing the Spring class with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method and press `run` I get the error message

```
Editor does not contain a main type
```

What do I do wrong? How do I make it run and how do I create other Spring projects from the generated `pom.xml` file now? I don't know about Java dependency resolution or packet managing.

Answer (score 2):

The archive file generated by https://start.spring.io/ is just that: a simple archive. Eclipse does not understand what's really inside it. Selecting `File -> Import -> General -> Archive File` will just copy whatever is inside it (which happens to be a [Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)) and put it inside an existing Eclipse project, which is useless.

This explains the `Editor does not contain a main type` error, because Eclipse has not imported the project correctly, so the Java file is not being treated as code by Eclipse.

What should be done instead: unzip the archive, and select `File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects`, then point the Root Directory to the directory containing the `pom.xml` file (the file used by Maven to configure and build your Maven project). Once that is finished, you should have a Maven project in Eclipse that you can browse, edit and run.

Comment: Would you kindly tell me how I would now proceed to the next step "Set up a Spring Boot Application" in the tutorial in eclipse? Where do I have to create the new project in the workbench tree? It must have some connection to the `pom.xml` file I guess. Thank you very much.

Comment: @vonspotz When you import the project using `File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects`, it should already exist in your workspace now. The remaining part is to create new files for classes, and so on.

Comment: Hello M A, the tutorial says "Now you can create a simple application:"; "src/main/java/hello/Application.java" - I don't know how this file should fit into the structure of the unzipped file. Are you sure that what they mean is that I should use this structure with that `pom.xml` from the unzipped file? Then, as I said, I don't know where "hello" should fit in. Also then I would have two files with a `main(String args[])` I am new to Java/Eclipse. What is that what I created via the import even named? It is in the "Package explorer" so I deduce it is a "package" ? And I can't in that package

Comment: create another project, able to make use of the same dependencies? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

***File > Open Projects from File System...*** (alias [*Smart Import*](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import)) detects and configures the projects and also works with ZIP archives.

In this case, when there is a `pom.xml` file, *File > Import...: Maven > Existing Maven Projects* would also work after unzipping the ZIP file. But *File > Open Projects from File System...* works for more cases and the archive does not need to be unzipped first.

Depending on the Java version you are using, you might also need to configured the required Java SDK in *Window > **Preferences: Java > Installed JREs***.