# How do I create a Spring project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, docker

I am absolutely new to eclipse and Spring.

How do I create a Spring Java project in Eclipse ?

I am following the instructions to create a Spring Project with Docker [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159265/how-do-i-import-a-java-project-into-my-workspace-correctly-and-make-it-run) I successfully imported the zip file generated through https://start.spring.io/ under the point `Starting with Spring Initializr` in the above-mentioned tutorial.

What follows in the tutorial is the point `Set up a Spring Boot Application`

```
Now you can create a simple application:

src/main/java/hello/Application.java

package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "Hello Docker World";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

My question is, **where** or **how** I create this application and how this is connected to the imported above mentioned zip file and its' `pom.xml` file ?

EDIT:

Where am I supposed to issue the command

```
./mvnw package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
```

as stated in the tutorial ? I hate tutorials where you lose time for no reason because the author can't just state things clearly. For what do they write a tutorial if you have to ask then on SO anyway?

EDIT 2:

When issuing

```
mvn hello
```

in

```
/eclipse/workspace2021/Spring Hello World/src/
```

I get the following error message

```
workspace2021/Spring Hello World/src$ mvn hello
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.083 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-29T14:54:06+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/media/max/KINGSTON/eclipse/workspace2021/Spring Hello World/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: partially related comment: If you want to go ahead with Eclipse, there's both a plugin set as well as a pre-configured bundle of Eclipse for Spring called the "Spring Tool Suite", or "STS" for short. That might handle some things you will encounter on your path forward

Comment: Thanks kasoban, but I would first like to go through the tutorial from point to point, first things first. I mean, the STS is mentioned in the tutorial too. But it's mentioned as a side-note. It's ridiculous how steep the learning curve is just to create a Spring Project. I am not a total noob to programming. I am just not accostumed to the Java IDE and its project management/dependency resolution mechanisms.

@SoftwareEngineer I am not using Windows. Bad answer.

Comment: Please look at my edit, too. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `./mvnw package` which requires Maven to be installed on your system, you can run a Maven launch configuration (_Run > Run Configuration_) with the goal `package` in that directory. This should be generate the file `target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar` that has to be executed with Java.

Comment: Hello @howlger, Thank you very much for your answer. 1) `Instead of ./mvnw package which requires Maven to be installed on your system,` I have it installed. But this seems to require a mvnw file in the directory where it is supposed to be executed. And what would be the `cwd` for that command to be issued? 2) How to I "set the goal `package` in that directory" ? What do I have to select before invoking the *Run > Run Configuration* dialogue? The class file with the `main` function in it or the package folder?

Comment: On the command line `mvn package` and then `java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar` does the same in two steps instead of in one.

Comment: Ok. The tutorial-command executes a maven wrapper. I can neither find the mavenwrapper nor the pom.xml file in my eclipse workspace. is that normal ? However, what is the aim? Is the (intermediary) aim to generate a `maven-build` ?

Comment: Yes ok. Please look at my edit 2

Comment: @vonspotz What does windows have to do with it?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Nothing. You are referring to a reply to a comment of you that was deleted for good reasons.

Comment: `mvn hello` expects a `pom.xml` file in the current/working/base directory. Is there a `pom.xml` file in the parent directory of the `src` sub-directory?

Comment: No there is not. My workbench directory and the folder tree in the eclipse project explorer are totally different. In the project explorer for instance the project is under `src/main/java/hello/Application.java` well in the maven project folder. But in the workbench directory it is not in the maven project folder structure but the project folder is a sibling to the maven project folder structure where the pom.xml resides.

Comment: The file `Application.java` from the eclipse project explorer is called `module-info.java` in the workbench directory.

Comment: In the *Run > Run Configuration" dialogue, if I have the project selected, how do I create a maven JAR ? There is only the button "Run". But that doesn't create a `gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar` in the workbench directory